# Model ID property null in ASP.NET MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model expense

```
public class Expense
{
     public int expenseID {get;set;}
     public string expenseName {get;set;}
     public int reportID {get;set;}
}
```

I have a controller method which should pass an expense object to the view

```
public ActionResult Create(int reportID)
{
    Expense ex = new Expense(){ 
        reportID = reportID
    };
    return View(ex);
}
```

Then in the view the user can set the expenseName property and I have included

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.expenseID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.reportID)
```

Then another controller method accepts the Expense model and should save it to the database however the expenseID is null and a database error occurs
This is the controller method

```
public ActionResult Create(Expense ex)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Expenses.Add(ex);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(ex);
}
```

Can anyone suggest why the expenseID property is null when we try and add expense to our database thanks!

Comment: Did you debug the action Create? And here you see while you create the expense object in action Create you are just initializing reportid not the expenseId.  And @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.expenseID) don't have any value except null.

Comment: From what I can see is that you only pass in `reportID` in `Expense ex` object and return to View. Then in your view you set a `HiddenFor(model => model.expenseID) which doesn't have anything in it. I think that this is the problem you are facing.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the object Expense before you pass it to your view in the GET ActionResult method. But it looks like you don't have a constructor to assign an ID on model instantiation. If you want the database to assign the ID on insert, you want Identity Specification set to true on that property, otherwise it will try and insert the row without a primary key. Are you using Entity Framework for data access, this may be more of an EF config problem if you are.

Comment: Maybe try and put a breakpoint  on the ID on your create view and check to see whether the ID has a value before you POST it

Comment: 1. Just add [Key] before public int expenseID {get;set;} (if you think this is not duplicate in database). 2. Look into your view source if you can see expenseID hidden input with value?

Comment: Based on the code you have shown, `expenseID` will never be `null`, but it will always be `0` (the default for `int`) because you never set it anywhere.

Comment: @StephenMuecke should the expenseID not be autogenerated when the expense object is created, as this is my primary key in the Expense model?

Comment: @CatherineG, If the property is marked with `[Key]` (so its an auto-incremented property in the database), then the value of `expenseID` will be set after calling `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks I'll have amother look aty model class and make sure it's set as the key

Answer (score 0):

expenseID property is null. Because You setting property expenseID not null and you insert expenseID = null in database => error. And model expense you need update again same that:

```
public class Expense
{
     [Key]
     public int expenseID {get;set;}
     public string expenseName {get;set;}
     public int reportID {get;set;}
}
```

And Property expenseID in database if you don't setting "Identity Specification" => expenseID don't auto have new key ID.

Comment: Please try to understand the problem.

Comment: I Thinks his problem, it in such contents :). are you thinks?

Comment: @LinhTuan Adding `[Key]` can only solve the problem partially , what the OP needs is that the expenseID be populated before passing to the View as @Html.HiddenFor.

Comment: @ShawnYan yes, i undestand. In this case we are can check all case.

Comment: @LinhTuan Right I understand.

Comment: He need to fetch the max expenseid and increment by 1 and have to save in database. he can fetch the expenseid either in httprequest Create action method or in the form postback create method.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `HiddenFor` properties are within your BeginForm using statement:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "YourController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.expenseID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.reportID)

    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Post Data">
}
```

Have you set a breakpoint on the Create Action Method to make sure that the Expense model is definitely not null itself when it arrives, if its not then my above suggestion should fix it.

**edit**
This is assuming your ID is populated when you pass it out to your view in the first place, and is not yet to be actually created in the db as Linh Tuan suggested.

If you are using EF, you should make sure your config is something like this:

```
public ExpenseConfiguration()
{
    HasKey(x => x.expenseId);
}
```

You should check the Design of that table, and see whether Identity Specification is set to true, if it is, it doesn't matter whether the `expenseId` is null all the way to INSERT, the db will assign it an incrementing ID once it get to the point of insert.

Your GET method seems to be expecting a reportId as a parameter, could you tell us what is feeding this `ActionMethod` in the first place, as if you already have an ID that you wish to re-use for your Expense object table then it might just be a case of not passing the `HiddenFor` property correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `expenseID` is set as an Identity Column in your database and mapping, you will have to set expenseID explicitly.

Something like this :

```
public ActionResult Create(int reportID)
{
    Expense ex = new Expense(){ 
        reportID = reportID,
        expenseID = **Some value** //Not advisable though

    };
    return View(ex);
}
```

However the preferred method would be to make your `expenseId` Column as Identity column and make it automatically incremented,  like this :

```
public class Expense
{
     [Key]
     public int expenseID {get;set;}
     public string expenseName {get;set;}
     public int reportID {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [HttpPost] attribute to second ActionMethod.And parameter must be "Expense model"

Comment: The parameter doesn't need to be specifically "Expense model" as long as you are passing the object with the same type to controller.

Answer (score 0):

My hidden field is inside form.

**Model:**

```
public class Operations
{        
    public decimal firstValue { get; set; }        
}
```

**First Action Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Operations model = new Operations();
    model.firstValue = 100M;
    return View(model);
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.firstValue)
@Html.ActionLink("MyLink", "SampleGet", Model)//(for redirection)
```

**Target Action Method:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SampleGet(Operations model)
{
    decimal myValue = model.firstValue;
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve this in 2 ways.**

**1.** From create method you not sending any  expenseID  to the view through model. You have to initilize ex.expenseID  in action method Create.

```
   public ActionResult Create(int reportID, int expenseID )
    {
        Expense ex = new Expense(){ 
            reportID = reportID,
            expenseID = expenseID /** Or expenseID = max(expenseID) +1 from expense table in database*/  
        };
        return View(ex);
    }
```

**2. Or** in post back create method

```
public ActionResult Create(Expense ex)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ex.expenseID = db.Expenses.Max( x => x.expenseID) + 1 ; 
        db.Expenses.Add(ex);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
   return View(ex);
```

Comment: The problem is we don't know what is being used for data access, this is EF related code and as a side note I think stuff like this belongs in a repository layer, not the Controller.

Comment: hmm, I have just make direction to get the ex.expenseId , so that he can go the right place.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either pass the expenseID property value while creating new record.
Else u can make expenseid as identity column by including this in your Context Class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {           

            modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Expense>().HasKey(a => a.expenseID);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Expense>().Property(a => a.expenseID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly initialised your `expenseID`.

Yes, I know, we can expect that `int` will be initialised with `0` - but in my case it's not working when you passing object `controller -> view (with hidden) -> controller`. I'm not sure why.

Try something like that:

```
public ActionResult Create(int reportID)
{
    Expense ex = new Expense(){ 
        expenseID = 0,
        reportID = reportID,
    };
    return View(ex);
}
```

I suppose that `expenseID` is your Primary Key in Db, so EF will compute proper `Id` when you set `expenseID = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

If expenseID is your key, you should modify your code with these two line before

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int expenseID {get;set;}
```